# Database query to JsonArray

Tags: json, arrays

I´m getting data from a database, the query works in the correct way, but I want to save that data in JsonArray.

```
while(rset.next()){
for(int i=0;i<numeroColumnas;i++){
              json.addProperty(key[0], rset.getInt(key[0]));
             json.addProperty(key[1], rset.getString(key[1]));
            json.addProperty(key[2], rset.getString(key[2]));
            json.addProperty(key[3], rset.getInt(key[3]));
           json.addProperty(key[4], rset.getDouble(key[4]));
          json.addProperty(key[5], rset.getDouble(key[5]));
     }
    ajson.add(json);
   System.out.println("Cadena JSON:" +ajson.toString());
```

}

This code generates an incorrect output, I get repeat values:

> Cadena JSON:[{"IDCOORD":1,"HORA":"2012-02-13 07:58:06.146","FECHA":"2012-02-13 >07:58:03","COOR_IDEQUIPO":1,"LATITUD":28.56245,"LONGITUD":-16.7000555}]
>
> [{"IDCOORD":2,"HORA":"2012-02-13 07:59:41.881","FECHA":"2012-02-13 >07:59:39","COOR_IDEQUIPO":1,"LATITUD":-4.7152449,"LONGITUD":41.6514567},
> {"IDCOORD":2,"HORA":"2012->02-13 07:59:41.881","FECHA":"2012-02-13 >07:59:39","COOR_IDEQUIPO":1,"LATITUD":->4.7152449,"LONGITUD":41.6514567}]

I´m pretty sure that I´m doing something wrong on while. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry :(, I´ve found the mistake:

```
JSONArray ajson = new JSONArray();

while(rset.next()){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("id_coord", rset.getInt(key[0]));
    json.put("fecha_servidor", rset.getString(key[1]));
    json.put("fecha_movil", rset.getString(key[2]));
    json.put("id_equipo", rset.getInt(key[3]));
    json.put("latitud", rset.getDouble(key[4]));
    json.put("longitud", rset.getDouble(key[5]));
    System.out.println("Cadena JSON:" +json);
    ajson.put(json);
}
```